# Using both ShowTaskpane and ExecuteFunction together

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

How can I change (hide a part of the ribbon or use protected view) in excel add ins office.js?

```
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>toggleProtection</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
 <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a URL resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
```

Is there anyway I can use both above together?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether the same button/menu item can both open a task pane and execute a function, then I'm afraid that it not possible. The two actions would have to have the different buttons/menu items. A possible workaround is to have startup logic in the task pane that does the work of the function. The effect would be that the task pane would open and the work would be done.

UPDATE in light of OP's comment:

It is also not possible to hide or protect the buttons/menu items that you create as part of an Office JavaScript Add-in. But it would be a valuable feature. Please go to [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and suggest this, or vote up the suggestion if someone has already made it.

Comment: well what I want is to hide some buttons in the ribbon when a button clicked to open the taskpane as some buttons are  not needed for that particular taskpane. if I can make the buttons to protected view, that's also fine if hiding is not possible

Comment: It is an old thread but has relevant information. @Rick Kirkham, I need to know if any function that can be execute while loading Word/Excel/PowerPoint to disable/Enable the ribbons. Here I am not talking about show/hide.

Comment: @S.PSingh See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

Comment: Thanks @RickKirkham, I want to execute the functions on loading of page (Word/Excel/PowerPoint) or during loading of add-ins tab. Is it possible?